# Is there any generic functions to assign column names in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

is there any generic functions to assign column names in pyspark ?instead of _1,_2,_3....... it has to give col_1,col_2,col_3

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| _5| _6| _7| _8| _9|_10|_11|_12|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  1|   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```py
df.toDF(*["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(1,len(df.columns)+1)])
```

Comment: df_split=index.select(sf.split(index.binary,"")).rdd.flatMap(lambda X: X).toDF(*["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(1,len(index.columns)+1)]) by trying this getting below error TypeError: toDF() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 10 were given

Comment: @mounikareddy, `.toDF(..)` is method from Dataframe and not from the RDD. Not sure why you are converting the DF to RDD

Comment: im new cto pyspark 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'flatMap' so im using rdd