# Is there any generic function to finding the column names in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

how to print column names in generic way. I want col1,col2,… instead of _1,_2,…

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3| _4| _5| _6| _7| _8| _9|_10|_11|_12|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|  0|   |
```

Comment: I just answered the similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259555/is-there-any-generic-functions-to-assign-column-names-in-pyspark

Comment: that one not working...it is showing error like this,  df_split=index.select(sf.split(index.binary,"")).rdd.flatMap(lambda X: X).toDF(*["col_{}".format(i) for i in range(1,len(index.columns)+1)])
TypeError: toDF() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 10 were given

Comment: Are you the same user having 2 accounts?

Comment: df_split=index.select(sf.split(index.binary,""),"binary").rdd.flatMap(lambda X: X).toDF()

Comment: Why is this required? `.rdd.flatMap(lambda X: X).`

Comment: | _1| _2| _3| _4| _5| _6| _7| _8| _9|_10|_11|_12|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|   |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change dataframe column names in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077353/how-to-change-dataframe-column-names-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

assuming `df` is your dataframe, you can juste rename :

```
for col in df.columns: 
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replace("_", "col"))
```